# yeoman automated javascript package references in app/index.html

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, bower

I have generated an AngularJS project with yeoman, and have the standard 'Allo, 'Allo! page working.

I then decided to add restangular to the project, so executed "bower install restangular" which correctly installed the package (bower list shows the restangular reference).

However, I expected the index.html file to automatically be update with the correct script references to restangular and its dependencies.

Am I using the wrong yeoman convention for installing additional dependencies?

Answer (score 5):

Adam is correct. The most reliable way to handle this is to go fishing through `bower_components/your-installed-package/` for the file you want to include. Currently, Bower is not consistently being used by the package authors. More specifically, some authors specify a `bower.json` with `"main": "path/to/file.js"` defined. However, some/most don't. Without that defined, there's a limit on how much magic can happen, since it's up to a script's best guess what the main file is that should be included.

I wrote up a grunt task to try to help with this, however, that will inject a script when a package has the `main` property defined: https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-bower-install

Instead of typing `bower install jquery --save`, you would say: `grunt bower-install:jquery`

If you give it a shot, let me know how it goes!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with grunt-bower-install https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-bower-install . Follow his instructions like adding the config to your Gruntfile, and adding the comment block to your index.html .

Install the package you want using `bower install yourpackage -S` . You need the -S for it to be added to bower.json

If bower-install tells you it cannot get it automatically, go to app/bower_components/yourpackage/bower.json and add in `"main": "path/to/file.js"`

You can do multiple files with an array, for example:

`"main": ["lib/persistence.js", "lib/persistence.store.mysql.js", "lib/persistence.sync.js"]`

I also found it useful to add bower-install to the common grunt tasks so that you don't need to call `grunt bower-install`. Here is adding it to the `grunt serve` task:

```
grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
  return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
}

grunt.task.run([
  'bower-install',
  'clean:server',
  'concurrent:server',
  'autoprefixer',
  'connect:livereload',
  'watch'
]);
```

});

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](http://yeoman.io/packagemanager.html):

> The easiest approach to use a Bower package statically is to just reference the package manually from a script tag:

```
<script src="bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
```

Sounds like you are on the right track. Just add the script tag to your HTML.